# In MATLAB, is it possible to have a 'for' loop straight after an 'elseif', and if not, how do I circumvent this?

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop, vector

Say I have the following:

vector = [1,2,3];

```
if length(vector) > 5
error ('Vector too long')
elseif
 for k = 1:length(vector)
 vector(1,k) < vector(1,k+1)
error ('Elements in vector not in ascending order')
else
...
```

I cannot seem to get this to work, nor can I see an obvious way to get around this problem.

Comment: You mean like having a loop without specifying the condition of `elseif` ? If yes, why do you want to do that? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to check whether the elements of the vector are in ascending order.

Comment: You don't need the `elseif` the `error` command will terminate execution.

Comment: Just use `sort` and see if the vector matches after you `sort` it

Comment: what's the status of this rather old question? There was an answer given but no comment was placed under it as to if it didn't work, nor was it accepted in order to mark the question as solved, if solved. @EuxLuxed

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this.  Given `v` and wanting to know if it's sorted.

```
v = [1,2,3];
isSorted = all(v == sort(v));
```

See [sort](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) for documentation of what sort can do.  See [all](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) for a description of what all does.

There is even a function that does this directly.  It is called...`issorted`.  The usage is `isSorted = issorted(v);`